# Particals not playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the gameObject collides with the player the print function inside the if statement works. The Debug.Log shows the correct object (Partical system) is initialized. I can see the Partical system showing the effects when dropped directed to the scene. But when playing the game I cant see the effect playing. What could be wrong

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collidedwith)
    {
        
        if (collidedwith.gameObject.CompareTag ("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log(explosionEffect);
            explosionEffect.Play();
            print("Hit the player");
            //Destroy(collidedwith.gameObject);
        }

    }
```

The collision detection is continuous.

Comment: Could be a layer issue. Does your camera filter layers? Are the particles in the camera frustum?

Comment: Have you checked the location and orientation of `explosionEffect` to ensure it's where you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. instead of `explosionEffect.play()` I used `Instantiate(explosionEffect.gameObject, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);` . I dont know if its the best way to do things but it works.